# Update text box on web page before starting a long JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms

Title quite much describes the goal.

I want to place into a text box "start" in a text box, and then run some processing.

When done, I'll update the text box.

Not looking for a countdown timer.
Not looking for a progress bar.
Not looking or care about updates during this processing loop.

Simple want to update text box at the start of the process in JavaScript, and then at the end.

I have this simple example code that shows this issue:

```
       <input id="cmdStart" type="button" value="Start" onclick="mytest()" />

        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="18px" Width="319px" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <br />

        <script>

            function mytest() {

                t = Date.now()

                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "start loop"

                for (i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) { }

                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value =
                    "Done seconds = " + ((Date.now() - t) / 1000).toString()
            }

        </script>
```

Of course I ONLY see the end results of the code running.

so, the code runs, but never displays the "start loop" part.

how can this be done? Links to a simple example (not a countdown) are welcome.

The loop of course takes a few seconds - results do show.

So how can I get the text box to show some text at the start of this js code?

I am somewhat new to JavaScript. In just about every platform I used, there is usually some kind of event que flush() or DoEvents or some such to update (execute) the event/update "que". However, I am unable to find anything like this in JavaScript.

Is there something I am missing? I do grasp the single thread model that the browser has (for running js code), and I do grasp the event model.

And I do see that such updating of the DOM is not all that easy if the browser is busy.

I worked on just about every software system and platform. However, js seems lacking in this area.

How can I get the text box to update with some text at the start of my simple js routine?

The code works, and displays the results, but never displays the "start loop" in the text box.

And I not been able to find a working demo, or example for the above. As noted, some are count down examples - not at all worried or care or need some count down. But I do need to learn/know how to update a text box on a web page at the start of running some code.

Edit, ok, the suggestion was to use await, but it produces the same results.

I now have with await this setup:

```
        <script>

            async function setmytextbox() {

                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "start loop"
                return 1
            }

            async function mytest() {

                await setmytextbox

                t = Date.now()
                for (i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) { }

                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value =
                    "Done seconds = " + ((Date.now() - t) / 1000).toString()
            }

        </script>
```

Still does not update the text box at the start.

Edit #2 - suggestion in comments to try setTimeout.

So, I have this, - still does not work

```
        <script>

            function mytest() {

                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "start loop"

                t = Date.now()

                setTimeout(bigloop(), 50)

                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value =
                    "Done seconds = " + ((Date.now() - t) / 1000).toString()
            }


            function bigloop() {
                for (i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) { }
            }

        </script>
```

As per comments, I had bigloop() in the setTimeout, WRONG!

So, removing the (), setTimeout works, but of course becomes async, and thus the text for the time out of course displays right away.

So, this now works:

```
        <script>

            function showstart() {
                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "start loop"
                }

            function mytest() {

                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "start loop"
                setTimeout(bigloop, 0)

            }

            function bigloop() {
                t = Date.now()
                for (i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) { }

                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value =
                    "Done seconds = " + ((Date.now() - t) / 1000).toString()
            }

        </script>
```

Edit, await is quite nice, and this code works

```
         async function bigloop2() {
                for (i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) { }
                return 1

            }

            async function mytest2() {

                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "start loop"

                t = Date.now()
                await bigloop2

                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value =
                    "Done seconds = " + ((Date.now() - t) / 1000).toString()


            }
```

for those landing here???

My BIG BAD and pointed out kindly in comments was I was placing "()" at the end of my functions - (habit from c#). This meant that a call back was never being created - only a return value of that function.

I like the await (first time I made it work!). And it rather nice. I did not have to wire up a bunch of promise code, and unlike the setTimeout, I did not have to move the update code to the timer routine. (and I used await a lot in .net and android - but never could get it to work until now and the above example).

Comment: You could put your long-running work inside a setTimeout to achieve this.

Comment: Ok, the async + await suggesting did not work. I have a 3rd example and edit using setTimer. Still does not work, still does not show the starting text. Perhaps I am using setTimer wrong, but I don't think I am - (example I tested is included in my edit).

Comment: setTimeout takes a function as an argument but you seem to be calling it with the result of your function. So bigloop is actually executed before setTimeout is called in your example.

Comment: The function name is bigloop().  looks ok to me. It not returning anything - just runs function called bigloop(). setTimeout( "function name", delay). I have setTimeout(bigloop(), 50). ---- in fact I put a alert right before the setTimeout, and one right after - it is working - just not displaying the starting text.

Comment: No. bigloop() is the result of the function. bigloop without the parens is the function.

Comment: Sure but in either case, it will run. (but yes, I removed the (), and still same result).

Comment: ok see my edit - setTimeout(bigloop,0) works - thank you kindly. I'll try another whack at the async/awit - it should have worked too. But - thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make your script asynchronous. That is, you would need to `await` for the `for` loop to finish.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: I updated my code with async, and await - still does not work. See my edit  with await.

Comment: Don't just provide a link, provide code that addresses the problem asked. Link only sources are discouraged, even if they are from a reliable source

Comment: I agree. I did give the await code a try - first time, did not work. But, the 2nd time and posted code I have now works (before making this post, I MOST certainly did try await - but I had it wrong (was using () at end of my function names - that results in no call back